# Combinatorics with marbles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

There are $4$ bags of $10$ different colored marbles each; red, orange, yellow, green.

1. How many marbles do I have to pull out of the bag to get **one** matching pair.

My Solution: We would have to pull out $\boxed{10}$ marbles at minimum, this would guarantee a pair of each color.

2. How many marbles do I have to pull out of the bag to get **two** matching pair.

My Solution: We would have to pull out $\boxed{20}$ marbles at minimum, this would guarantee two pairs of each color.

3. How many marbles do I have to pull out of the bag to get **two** pairs of **different colored** marbles.

My Solution: We would have to pull out $\boxed{12}$ marbles at minimum, picking out a set of $10$ marbles that is one color, then $2$ more of another color.

Am I correct for these? Please correct me if I am not. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread the question.  I assumed one bag of forty marbles.

Comment: Are there forty marbles of each colour total?

Comment: Yes, You are correct. There are 10 marbles in each bag/

Comment: To clarify:   one bag of 10 red marbles, one bag of 10 orange marbles, one bag of 10 yellow marbles, and one bag of 10 green marbles?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :)

Comment: Then my answer is incorrect!

Comment: Let me restate: There are $4$ bags of marbles; $10$ red marbles, $10$ orange marbles, $10$ yellow marbles, and $10$ green marbles. Each of these $10$ marbles are in a singular bag, not all together. How many marbles do I have to pull out of the bags to get at least one matching pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can pull out four (one of each colour) and still not have a pair, but as soon as you pull out the fifth one, it will match one of the colours you already have.  Therefore, the answer is $\boxed{5}$.
2. You can pull out six (three of one colour, one each of the rest) and still have only one pair, but as soon as you pull out the seventh one, it will match one of the colours you already have.  Therefore, the answer is $\boxed{7}$.
3. You can pull out thirteen (ten of one colour, one each of the rest) and still have only one pair, but as soon as you pull out the fourteenth one, it will match one of the colours you already have.  Therefore, the answer is $\boxed{14}$.

This is an application of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).